# Correct log file format spanning multiple lines

Tags: powershell, line, break

I am looking to create a script allowing me to correct the format of a log file that has been incorrectly generated for several months which gave the format below

```
xx-xxx-20xx xx:xx:xx INFO : xxxx-x : Demande d'envoi du mail Sujet: XXX - XXXXX
 / EQUIPEMENT / Arrivée:20xx-xx-xx
xx-xxx-20xx xx:xx:xx INFO : xxxx-x : Demande d'envoi du mail Sujet: XXX - XXXXX
 / ACCI / Arrivée:20xx-xx-xx
xx-xxx-20xx xx:xx:xx INFO : xxxx-x : Demande d'envoi du mail Sujet: XXX - XXXXX
 / CMS / Arrivée:20xx-xx-xx
```

I am looking to correct the format below

```
xx-xxx-20xx xx:xx:xx INFO : xxxx-x : Demande d'envoi du mail Sujet: XXX - XXXXX / EQUIPEMENT / Arrivée:20xx-xx-xx
xx-xxx-20xx xx:xx:xx INFO : xxxx-x : Demande d'envoi du mail Sujet: XXX - XXXXX / ACCI / Arrivée:20xx-xx-xx
xx-xxx-20xx xx:xx:xx INFO : xxxx-x : Demande d'envoi du mail Sujet: XXX - XXXXX / CMS / Arrivée:20xx-xx-xx
```

I’m trying to use a clear log script that I’ve already created:

```
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$ADRESSE = $scriptPath
$TEXT1 = ' / EQUIPEMENT*'
$TEXT2 = ' / ACCI*'
$TEXT3 = ' / CMS*'


$files = Get-ChildItem $ADRESSE -Filter LogSplitterProd_20200918_1740.log
foreach ($f in $files)
{
    $outfile = $f.FullName
    $GetLastWriteFile = Get-Item $outfile
    $LastWriteFile = $GetLastWriteFile.LastWriteTime
    If ((Get-Item $outfile).length -gt 2kb)
    {
        $data = foreach($line in Get-Content $outfile )
        {
            if($line -like $TEXT1 -Or $line -like $TEXT2 -Or $line -like $TEXT3) 
            {
                #$line=$line -replace ("`n`r","") #TEST1
                #$line=$line -replace ("``n``r","") #TEST2
                #$line=$line.replace("`n",", ").replace("`r",", ") #TEST3
                #$line=$line -replace("`n",", ") #TEST4
                #$line=$line -replace("`r",", ") #TEST4
                #$line=$line -replace("`n`r",", ") #TEST5
            }
            else
            {
                $line
            }
        }
        $data | Set-Content $outfile -Force
    }
    $GetLastWriteFile.LastWriteTime = $LastWriteFile
    Write-Host "Save et date $outfile terminé"
}
#start-sleep 5
```

Comment: Read the file as a multi-line string, then run a regex replace on new line characters followed by a negative lookahead for your date/time stamp? `(Get-Content $outfile -raw) -replace '\n(?!..-...-20.. ..:..:..)'` or something like that.

Comment: That works perfect, why not make it an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to use `switch` with parameters `Regex` and `File` :

```
$result = switch -Regex -File 'D:\Test\some.log' {
    '^\s\/'  { $line + $_ ; $line = '' }
    default  { $line = $_ }
} 

# output on screen
$result

#output to new log file
$result | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\new.log'
```

Output:

```
xx-xxx-20xx xx:xx:xx INFO : xxxx-x : Demande d'envoi du mail Sujet: XXX - XXXXX / EQUIPEMENT / Arrivée:20xx-xx-xx
xx-xxx-20xx xx:xx:xx INFO : xxxx-x : Demande d'envoi du mail Sujet: XXX - XXXXX / ACCI / Arrivée:20xx-xx-xx
xx-xxx-20xx xx:xx:xx INFO : xxxx-x : Demande d'envoi du mail Sujet: XXX - XXXXX / CMS / Arrivée:20xx-xx-xx
```

Comment: Thanks the answer is just perfect it works great and only changes the lines that need to be changed thanks again.
Only thing is that I don’t understand how it works so if I have to change it I might have a little trouble.

Comment: @vincent1890 With `switch -Regex -File` it iterates through every line in the text file. The regex expression `'^\s\/'` reacts on lines that start (`^`) with a whitespace character (`\s`), followed by a forward slash. (the backslash is there to regex escape this). If we find such a line, the should be the second part of the 'other' line we catch in the `default` switch case, so we output the combined line there and clear the 'normal' line for the next set of lines. Variable `$result` captures this, so that will become a string array with the updated content and lastly we write that to file.

Comment: thank you @Theo for the explanations I understand the code better now and it will save me several days compared to if I had to change manually.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your log files are consistently in the format you've specified, you can just read the source file 2 lines at a time and join them together:

```bsh
function Repair-LogFile
{
    param( $Logfile )
    
    $lineCount = 2;

    # read 2 lines of log file into a buffer,
    # then join them together and output the result
    Get-Content -Path $Logfile -Encoding UTF8 | foreach-object `
        -Begin {
            $buffer = @();
        } `
        -Process {
            $buffer += $_;
            if( $buffer.Length -eq $lineCount )
            {
                Write-Output ($buffer -join "");
                $buffer = @();
            }
        } `
        -End {
            if( $buffer.Length -gt 0 )
            {
                Write-Output ($buffer -join "");
            }
        }

}
```

Usage:

```bsh
Repair-LogFile -Logfile "C:\src\so\log.txt" | Set-Content -Path "c:\src\so\log2.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks the answer was almost what I was looking for but no there were other type of line which bugs the final result